# sed with argument variables in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sed, quoting

I want to write a script that extract lines from line n to m of the input.

doit.sh:

```
 sed -n -e '$1,$2p' input.txt


 ./doit.sh 3 10
```

But it gave me an error sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unknown command: `2'. What went wrong?

Comment: `$1` and `$2` won't be expanded within single quotes.

Comment: To use string interpolation you need to use double quotes